# How to use ConstraintLayout Barrier to position a view to the right of other views?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="One"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Two Two"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
            tools:text="Three"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to place the **text3 to the right of text1 and text2 using ConstraintLayout Barrier**, but the above places the text3 on top of text1 and text2. What's wrong with the above layout? How can I use the ConstraintLayout Barrier to put text3 to the right of text1 and text2?
[image]

Comment: I have found that the preview in Android studio doesn't always work for barrier (or group for that matter). Try actually building and running

Comment: Turns out it actually works, only the Android studio preview is not able to show it properly..
Updating constraintlayout lib "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha3" it also work in preview